# How to slide-up / slide-down the sub-titles when ".scheduler_default_tree_image_collapse" / ".scheduler_default_tree_image_expand" is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, daypilot

The question says it all.

I could not find any documentation where where the slide-up/slide-down could be used. Also, I could not attach any external event to make it happen.

http://javascript.daypilot.org/scheduler/

**[Added]**

To be more specific, how to slide-up/slide-down when the plus / minus buttons are clicked in http://javascript.daypilot.org/demo/scheduler/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To others who might be looking for similar feature ....

> Unfortunately, sliding animation during expanding and collapsing the tree nodes is not supported at the moment. There is no way to add it using custom code.

src: https://forums.daypilot.org/Topic.aspx/2769/how-to-slide-up-slide-down-the-sub-titles-when-schedulerdef

Its me who posted the question in daypilot forums.

:-(